# Stop D3 from 'springing' on start

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a network of nodes that needs to grow and shrink dynamically. When I add or remove nodes I redraw the whole network and when that happens the nodes will bounce and spring on the canvas until it settles. Load this example and see this 'spring' when the nodes are drawn on the canvas. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

I would like to stop this 'spring' or reduce it heavily but I have no idea how. I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to "fix" the nodes after the intial run. In d3v4, this can be done by setting the value of fx and fy on each node (i.e. fx = x, fy = y). In version 3, you can use the fixed keyword to fixed a node. (see [the force layout API](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) for more details.